# How to copy the file from one windows machine to another windows machine in a particular drive using batch script?

Tags: windows

In my windows server, am taking SQL DB backup in C drive. I wants to copy this .bak file to some other client windows machine in a particular drive with the current date using batch script. So that i can schedule this batch script using scheduled task. please help me out.

Can anyone, give a script to run this. thanks

Comment: What is the specific format of the filename you want?

Answer (score 4):

Batch files are always tricky to get just right. First I'd open a command line and see if you can copy between two machines using the following syntax:

```
copy C:\localfile.bak \\remotemachine\c$\Path\remotefile.bak
```

(where "remotemachine" is the name of the remote machine and "c$" is the drive you wish to copy to). You can then copy this into a batch file and set up a scheduled task.

As for renaming the file to have the current date and time, I suggest you start with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203090/how-to-get-current-datetime-on-windows-command-line-in-a-suitable-format-for-us) as it may involve some effort to get it into a format you want.